# Adjust jquery to correct responsive navigation panel

Tags: jquery, html, media

I am creating my first responsive website and going through a little learning curve with the side panel navigation... I actually found a bit of code on stackoverflow to used instead of the bloated pluggins I found online.

This is the temp website.
http://streamlinebuilderscorp.com.216-70-85-163.messtudios.com/

And the problem is when you resize the browser smaller the 690px the mobile navigation appears.. and everything seems to work fine on the iPhone but on the desktop if you leave the mobile side navigation open and then resize the browser more then 690 the css media query hides the panel and it doesn't reset the main navigation bar.

I appreciate the help in advanced.. Also I can make a jfiddle or something if requested.

- I assume the logic to fix this would be a jquery if resize greater then 690 execute the close click event but can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks,
-Muhu

Comment: Don't wait for a code sample request. **Just provide it**. Saves everybody time. Also if the source server goes down, the code sample stays, so users are able to understand the question in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for JavaScript. Add an overriding style to the container:

```
@media (min-width: 690px) {
    #container {
        margin-left: 0 !important; /* overrides inline styles */
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated the website.. works but the navigation stays open if you resize it back to less then 690.. is it possible to have it revert to a hidden menu with the hamburger icon back to the way it was?

Comment: `$(window).on('resize', function() { ... })`